# Displaying BLOB image from database yii 2

Tags: php, image, yii2

Hello I am using a table for the blob images that contains the images and a client column to reference it the question is how can I display an image blob based on the clientid so that I can show it in the webpage using yii 2?

Here is a screenshot of the table.

[image]

Because in this particular article I got the impression it is only uploading the image as BLOB.
[Yii2 Display image stored in BLOB database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629478/yii2-display-image-stored-in-blob-database-field)

But how do I make it so that I would only returning/displaying the blob from the database?

**EDIT 1**

I converted the answer into yii code.

Controller

```
public function DisplayBlob($clientid){
      $model = new Slimages();

      return $model->DisplayBlob($clientid);

    }
```

Here is the model.php

```
 public static function DisplayBlob($clientid){
    return static::find()->where(['clientid' => $clientid])->asArray()->all();
 //     $db = $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myenrollment"); //keep your database name
 //     $sql = "SELECT * FROM slimages WHERE clientid = $clientid"; // pass your clientid here
    // $statement = $db->query($sql);
    // $result = mysqli_fetch_array($statement);
    // return $result;
    //echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['Picture'] ).'"/>';
  }
```

View file

```
 <td colspan="2"><?php 
            $result = SiteController::DisplayBlob($_user);
            foreach($result as $image){
             // echo  'hello';
                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image['Picture'] ).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
            }


            ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database"); //keep your database name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE clientid = $id"; // pass your clientid here
$statement = $db->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($statement);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['Picture'] ).'"/>';
```

**Note : Please change the db details , table and column names as per your requirement.**

i hope this will help you. Feel free to comment.

Comment: I got it working on my webpage, but I am just wondering if there's any way of doing this in yii code?